# Unable to boot Ubuntu because of some kernel problem

Tags: boot, kernel

My PC was working fine until yesterday. Today, when I turned on the PC, the OS didn't even boot. I waited for 2-3 minutes but nothing happened. I pressed the restart button. Now the GRUB menu appeared and I chose the Ubuntu option. The OS booted and the Ubuntu logo appeared but the lock screen didn't appear. It was just loading. I waited for couple of minutes. Nothing happened. I also tried REISUB, but it didn't work. I pressed restart button once again. The GRUB menu appeared and I chose Ubuntu. This time I got this error:

[image: Kernel error]

I use only Ubuntu (not dual boot). My OS is Ubuntu 20.04. I didn't tinker with any important system files yesterday.

What should I do to fix my PC?

Output of `sudo umount /dev/sda`:

```
umount: /dev/sda: not mounted.
```

Output of `sudo fsck /dev/sda`:

```
fsck from util-linux 2.34
e2fsck 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in super-block
fsck.ext2: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
fsck.ext2: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sda

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>

Found a gpt partition table in /dev/sda
```

Comment: If the kernel panic'd, alt+sysrq+reisub won't work (kernel panic is a sign of a dead kernel so kernel cannot respond to any commands). I would boot *live* media & `fsck` (file system check) your system & any data partitions; then try again (if it dies, re-check partitions), then try an older kernel. Whilst using the *live* media I'd also look for clues, was any change made last session etc (which hopefully you'll remember, but scanning logs or command history helps jog your memory).

Comment: @guiverc I've added the outputs of some commands.

Comment: It looks like your ramdisk file is corrupt. Can you boot into Recovery Mode? If so, do `sudo update-initramfs -c -k $(uname -r)`. I'll post an answer on how to properly `fsck` your file system. Report back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**fsck**

To check/repair your file system...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB in “Try Ubuntu” mode
- open a `terminal` window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/sdXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdXX`, replacing `sdXX` with the number you found earlier
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

**ramdisk**

You probably have a corrupt ramdisk file.

In Recovery Mode...

- boot to GRUB menu

  - choose Additional Options

    - choose Recovery Mode

      - choose Root Access

`sudo update-initramfs -c -k $(uname -r)`

Comment: Can you please tell me how should I go to recovery mode?

Comment: @technastic_tc I updated my answer. Report back.

Comment: Should I replace `uname` with my username?

Comment: @technastic_tc No. Use the command exactly as I show it.

Comment: Ok. BTW, which one should I do first? fsck or ramdisk?

Comment: @technastic_tc To be really safe, do the `fsck` first.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113224/discussion-between-technastic-tc-and-heynnema).